# Naming convention for string instance variables

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I wonder if the following names follow standard naming convention:

```
NSString *valueString;

NSString *urlString;
```

I want to know the convention for Apple standard where `NSString` variable name ends with "string".  Is it correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

There is no published Apple standard regarding the use of [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) or not in objective-C code. The sample projects by Apple don't use it.

You should adopt the naming convention used by your team. If you work alone, suit yourself, you'll be the only person reading your code. The only naming conventions that I can think of that matter are those that affect key value coding and memory management.

Answer (score 0):

From the code samples i read, i don't think I've seen apple storing URL's as NSString as instance variables, it's usually an NSURL Instance.

Whether it's a URL to a remote or local location, I believe the most conventional thing to do would be to store it in the class as an NSURL, and when you need to work on the path, retreive the string using NSURL's absoluteString, and the name of the local NSString in that case would be "path/filePath/resourcePath/imagePath".

Personally i do use urlStr, urlString and such.